# Angular Structure Incorrect Somewhere

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

All i am trying to do is call my back-end through an ng-Click and $http.get. I am then trying to set the value of the item i get to show up in my html. Here is my structure. Not really getting any errors so any information on how to see where my code is incorrect would be great. Thanks.

HTML

```
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<script src="~/Scripts/profileController.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js">    </script>
```

```
<section ng-controller="profileController as vm">

    <div class="container">

        <div style="padding-left:20px; padding-right: 1000px; height:700px;">

            <h2>Create Profile</h2>

            <img src="app/img/user.png" />
            <label for="eventName">UserName: {{vm.newUser.UserName}}</label>
            <input id="eventName" ng-model="UserName" type="text" placeholder="Edit User Name" />
            <label for="eventName">Name: {{vm.nameName}}</label>
            <input id="eventName" ng-model="nameName" type="text" placeholder="Edit Name" />
            <label for="eventName">Age: {{vm.age}}</label>
            <input id="eventName" ng-model="age" type="text" placeholder="Edit age" />
            <label for="eventName">College: {{vm.college}}</label>
            <input id="eventName" ng-model="college" type="text" placeholder="Edit college" />
            <label for="eventName">City: {{data.city}}</label>
            <input id="eventName" ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Edit city" />

            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="vm.getUserList()">Register</a>

        </div>
    </div>


</section>
```

CONTROLLER/FACTORY

```
 angular.module("app", [])
 .controller('profileController', ['$scope', 'profileFactory', function ($scope, profileFactory) {

var vm = this;
this.getUserList = function () {

    profileFactory.getUserList($scope).success(function (data) {
        $scope.UserList = data;
    });
}
 }])

 .factory('profileFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
var urlBase = "/api/saveUser";
var dealerProcessReportSetupFactory = {

    getUserList: function () {

        return $http.get(urlBase + "/UserList");
    }
};

return dealerProcessReportSetupFactory;
 }]);
```

API CONTROLLER

```
 public class profileController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/DealerProcessReportSetup
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("saveUser")]
    public tblOwl getUserList()
    {
        using (VSCDevEntities db = new VSCDevEntities()) 
        {
            var Owl = (from z in db.tblOwls select z).FirstOrDefault();

            return Owl;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you been able to step through the code if so what line is causing the issue that you are seeing..?

Comment: This is another reason i cant figure this one out, how do you step through an ng-Click?

Comment: @Zingo look at mine answer..that would help you..to make ng-click working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below things are missing

1. `ng-app` directive must be there in on the `body`/`html` tag like `ng-app="app"`.
2. Scripts should be loaded in header of your page.
3. You must be loading angular.js before loading any other file which is using angular object

References should be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/profileController.js"></script>
```

**Update**

As you are using `controllerAs` syntax your controller should use `this` keyword, Or atleast you should define `getUserList()` method in this keyword as you were used `ng-click="vm.getUserList()"`.

**Controller**

```
 angular.module("app", [])
 .controller('profileController', ['$scope', 'profileFactory', function ($scope, profileFactory) {
   var vm = this;
   this.getUserList = function () {

      profileFactory.getUserList($scope).success(function (data) {
          $scope.UserList = data;
      });
   } 
 }])
```